# How to measure performance of Angular.js application (not REST services)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Are there any tools to measure performance of Angular Application running in Browser?
I mean Application code not REST calls.

This came to mind when I build a Form into Application that contained a lots of tables made with HTML and ng-repeat. Especially Forms containing ng-repeat seems to be a bit of slower than I'm usually used to.

So, any tools or Best Practices available considering this issue?

Best Regrads,

Michael

Comment: Most browser's development tools have a profiling feature that you could use to do some performance analysis. If you want us to be able to help, we will have to see some code.

Comment: If you hadn't done so yet, install the extension for chrome [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en), it is great for debugging and profile AngularJS Apps

Comment: Thank you for this tip! Michael

Answer (score 1):

Batarang https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk is your tool! It's only available for chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Batarang is a neat tool, but right now adding as a chrome extension from the chrome webstore does not work, and building from the git-hub link requires an unpleasant amount of work.

As an alternative, if you are using the Chrome dev tools, there is a neat but semi-hidden tool in the 'Profiles' tab.

Choose 'Collect JavaScript CPU Profile', start, do something in your app, stop, then see your results (% or ms).  Click the triangle in the bottom of the screen (next to "bottom up", "top down" or something similar).  Then choose flame chart.  You can scroll through time, zoom in on processes, and clicking the process will take you to the code!

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't handle multiple and long ng-repeat well. You should consider paginating them. As for having performance metrics you could look into the possibilities given in the linked Thread.

[How Do I Measure the Performance of my AngularJS app's digest Cycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066422/how-do-i-measure-the-performance-of-my-angularjs-apps-digest-cycle)