# How to do a javascript profile of angular $digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a web app with portions written in angular, I have been using debugging tools to get information about how many times $digest is called and how much time it is taking. How can I get this information via a script? One way I thought of was adding timers etc to angular.js but I don't think changing angular.js code is a good approach in long term as new versions will be released in the future and I would have to add those timers again to the new versions. Is it possible to achieve this with javascript in another way?

Comment: My advice is not to manage the framework. It's very efficient.

Comment: Maybe this will be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066422/how-do-i-measure-the-performance-of-my-angularjs-apps-digest-cycle