# AngularJs: Testing performance

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, testing, web

Is there any good approach to test how much time processing of every user's action gets in web application based on AngularJs?

I would like to see how much time every element on every page in ms gets. Is there any out-of-box and ready-to-use solution for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The same way you profile any other webapp? Not sure what angular has to do with this...

Comment: This will likely get closed as off topic, but for [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855126/what-is-the-best-way-to-profile-javascript-execution)...

Comment: AngularJs has really specific render method (yep, it is all about digest). I'd like to use some tool that designed for that.

Comment: Again, I fail to see how that's relevant, the chrome devtools profiler will tell you how expensive your render method is (as well as all your other methods).

Comment: I know [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23066422/1575353) is specifically about the digest cycle but are answers on [it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23066422/1575353) helpful? I haven't worked with [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) much but it offers performance measurements ... I am trying to get something useful like the screenshots but maybe it has changed recently...