# How Do I Measure the Performance of my Angular app?

Tags: angular, performancecounter

There are ways of measure the performance for AngularJs app([How Do I Measure the Performance of my AngularJS app's digest Cycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066422/how-do-i-measure-the-performance-of-my-angularjs-apps-digest-cycle)). What about Angular app?Do we have something  inside Angular for this purpose ? Or third party library?

Comment: There is not any stand alone tool. But you can use your browsers profiling tool.

Comment: @alt255 What about continuously logging the response results? Are you suggesting a method along the lines of *let start = new Date()* in the *ngOnInit()* and then *util.Logify(new Date() - start)* at the end of the method? (Probably, in sharp version I'd prefer to connect it to life-time hooks but let's focus on a crude version for now.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten when debugging with chrome you can `console.profile('foo')` to set a point to start profiling on from and `console.profileEnd('foo')` to set finish point. The profile is added to profiles tab in dev tools

Comment: @alt255 Sorry for being unlear. I mean that I want to keep a log somehow. The users click and al lthe response times are logged for future reference. I even have a simple API that those calls might log to as a web service request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the chrome lighthouse tool to measure your application performance parameter,

here the link demonstrates how to use 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/

WebPageTest is also a very good tool, it performs website speed test from multiple locations around the globe using real browsers (IE and Chrome) and at real consumer connection speeds
https://www.webpagetest.org/